# How to change the log level of a ThresholdFilter programatically?

Tags: logging, log4j2

Today I have a requirement to change the log level for a specific appender programatically. The user should be able to set the level via rest interface or user input dialog. I played around with the classes to get the appender and the filter but this does not fit my expectations. The filter list is already empty. Below is a short snippet of my configuration:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="forum" monitorInterval="30">
  <properties>
    <property name="logging.statement.pattern">%d{DATE} %-5p %-20.20t %m [|] %l [|] %x [|] %t%n</property>
  </properties>

  <Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
    </Console>
    <RollingFile name="FileLogAppender" fileName="${sys:logging.target.dir}/dicom.log" filePattern="${sys:logging.target.dir}/output-%i.log">
      <ThresholdFilter level="INFO" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY" />
      <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>${logging.statement.pattern}</Pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
      <Policies>
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10MB" />
      </Policies>
      <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10" />
    </RollingFile>
  </Appenders>

  <Loggers>
    <Logger name="third.party.package" level="INFO" additivity="false">
      <AppenderRef ref="FileLogAppender" />
    </Logger>
    <Logger name="my.custom.package.internal" level="TRACE" additivity="false">
      <AppenderRef ref="FileLogAppender" />
    </Logger>
    <Logger name="my.standard.package" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
      <AppenderRef ref="FileLogAppender" />
    </Logger>

    <Root level="INFO">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

I used the *LogManager* class to get the configuration and then firstly I thought to get the appender specified by the name of the appender. But the appender does not offer the list of the filters so I can't iterate over them to get the *ThresholdFilter* and set the level. Another try was to get the filter list directly from the configuration. But this list seems to be empty every time. Can anybody give me a hint to looking for the right way to set the level?

Thanks in advance, Hardie

Answer (score 2):

An Appender only has a single filter. You get it by calling the getFilter method on the Appender. That filter might be a CompositeFilter, in which case it is a container of other filters and you would have to iterate through them to find the one you want. In your configuration above you would only have a single filter though.

However, the level in the ThresholdFilter is immutable so there is no setLevel method. You would need to write a custom version of the filter to be able to do that or create a Jira issue to have Log4j modified.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write a custom filter, your best bet is to extend [AbstractFilter](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/filter/AbstractFilter.html).